# Initializing instance of a class as null

Tags: java, class

Why is it like this?

Codes:

```
public class Class1 {
    Class1 c1
    public Class1() { c1 = null; }
}

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
        System.out.println(cs1 == null);
    }
}
```

In `Class1` I initialized the `c1` as `null` in its contructor. Then
when I instantiated the `Class1` in `Class2` then check if its value is really null `(cs1 == null)` the output it produces is `false`.
Why does it output as `false`? `cs1` is `null`, hence it's supposed to print as `true`. Why does this happen? Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks...

Comment: you you are checking cs1, not cs1.c1.    cs1 it not null. Use better variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You did initialize `c1` as null, yes, but `c1` is not the `Class1` being initialized in the constructor.

`new Anything()` is never, ever null.

Comment: yeah but `c1` is of type `Class1` so I thought that it should output as null as well. I'm still a little confused...

Comment: @robert: one is a local variable of type `Class1` and the other is a field inside `Class1` of type `Class1`. They have basically no relation to each other except that they hold the same type of value (a reference to an object of `Class1`). There's absolutely no reason why changing one of them should change the other as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Class1`‘s `c1` attribute is null, not the instance itself. So, basically you’ve created a wrapper around a null. This should print `true`:

```
System.out.println(cs1.c1 == null);
```